# Converting Menu Links to List Elements

Tags: php, css, headers

I'm creating a theme from a template based on Wordpress 3.0.  I've started with items like Starkers which is a completely bare theme, and even tried modifying something by default like Twenty Ten or Eleven.  However, the thing that gets me is how can I adjust the css to covert a single line of PHP such as (used as default now for navigation):

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
```

Or:

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'container_class' => 'menu-header',
        'theme_location'  => 'primary'
    )
);
?>
```

Into a stylized list element that can be adjusted to the length of the entire navigation menu?

I'm not understanding how the PHP is turned into the right amount of `<li>`'s (which is the case in the generated html viewable in Firebug or another inspector) where I can modify them how I wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wp_nav_menu()` pulls from the menus selected/generated in `Appearance -> Menus`. There will be one `<li>` for each item in the menu you select.

Comment: Thanks @m0r7if3r  Is this a function that is default for Wordpress?  I was trying to find how it parses this through the functions.php page but couldn't really see anything.  Happen to know where this functionality is built in? (I like to learn _how_ stuff works - and this just threw me for a loop)

Comment: `wp_nav_menu()` is a function built into wordpress. If you haven't yet, you should check out [what the codex has to say](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu).

Comment: Kudos to the codex reference, I appreciate that.